# jQuery datapicker noWeekends allow single weekend day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using the jQuery datapicker plugin, and am using the noWeekends function to disable weekends. The only issue is, I need to enable one single weekend day. Does anyone know how to do this? Here is the code I am using...

```
var disabledDays = [<?php echo rtrim($daysClosed, ","); ?>];

function nationalDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), 
        d = date.getDate(), 
        y = date.getFullYear();

    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if ($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
                return [false, disabledDays[i][2] + '_day'];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
}

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return noWeekend[0] ? nationalDays(date) : noWeekend;
    jQuery('.cart-contents i').html(noWeekend);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#e_deliverydate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
        minDate:<?php echo $delivMin; ?>,
        maxDate:'<?php echo $oneYearOn; ?>' 
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HZ5rw/)</kbd>

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 6)]; //0-Sunday 6-Saturday
    }
});
```

---

Updated after OP's comment

Disable all `28th Dec`

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HZ5rw/1)</kbd>

```
var array = ["28-12"];
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm', date);
        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    }
});
```

---

Disable `28th Dec 2013`

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HZ5rw/2)</kbd>

```
var array = ["28-12-2013"]; // add dates you want to disable here
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    }
});
```

---

To enable `28th Dec`

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HZ5rw/4)</kbd>

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        if (string == "28-12-2013") {
            return  [true];
        } else {
            var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != 6)];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't really help. I already have the function called `noWeekendsOrHolidays` which disables all weekends and any days that I define. I should have explained that I do not want to enable all Saturdays, just one day - 28th Dec. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. But it is still not right. Look at my code I posted in the original question and you will see that I have disabled ALL weekends and custom dates defined in `disabledDays`. Saturday 28th December being a weekend is disabled with my code, I want to know how to enable it. Thanks

Comment: @StuartTaylor-Jones Check updated answer and demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HZ5rw/4

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, thanks for all your help. The only issue is, the code you have supplied does not account for the predefined disabled days. I guess this rule needs to be added to the noWeekendsOrHolidays function, but I cannot figure this out. Any ideas? Thanks